# Extjs gridpanel docked panel

Tags: extjs

How can I add a panel to the dockedItems of a gridPanel in extended js?
On a gridpanel I need to add a panel to it's docked items on the bottom of it. This will be used for a live newsfeed

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just add the panel to bbar.

```
 bbar:[Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
    width:'100%',
    height:100,
    title:'Live Feed',
    items:[{text:'The Docked Panel'}],
}),{text:'hello'}]
```

I have created a fiddle.. refer it.[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LogeshSundar/262U4/1/)

Comment: thanks for the answer, however can you please explain how can I add to the main panel a pagingTool and beneath the paging tool this second panel? Well I managed to do this, but the two control appear one after the other, I need the panel to appear beneath the pagingtool

Comment: then you need to use the dockedItems config instead of the short form (bbar).
I have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LogeshSundar/262U4/10/

Comment: I need this for ext 3.4 sorry for mentioning this late